# Sh Loop command until return value =0

Tags: while-loop, sh

How to loop a command until a return value =0 in a sh script?
I need to run a ftp upload many times until this works (return value=0) maybe with a little sleep command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
until command here; do; done
```

You may want to `sleep` inside to not DoS the server or waste a lot of bandwidth:

```
until command here; do sleep 1; done
```

If your command contains semicolons, parenthesise it.